# how to update composite primary key values using hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have one table having composite primary key of four fileds like userId,firstname,lastname,password and if the user allowed to change these four values, based on which condition can i update these values in UserData table using hibernate

Comment: Primary Key is supposed to be unchanged. Instead of having that monster - create surrogate numerical PK based on a sequence.

Comment: talbe should not be changed because i am doing enhancement of existing project

Answer (score 1):

As You are updating composite primary key, the only way I can see is delete the existing record & insert the new record.